# Meteor method 404 error but logs in console

Tags: javascript, meteor

I call Meteor method but it is showing error message:

> Method 'users.insertotp' not found [404]

But somehow the console.log get executed, why?

what am i doing wrong here?

You can see the code here [github](https://github.com/mgonekar/Meteor-Test-App).

**File: imports/api/db.js**

```
export const Otp   = new Mongo.Collection('otp');
Meteor.methods({
    'users.insertotp' (otp) {
        // if(!this.userId) {
        //     throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        // }
        console.log('otp',otp);
        return Otp.insert({
            otp,
            userId: this.userId,
            updatedAt: moment().valueOf()
        });
    }
});
```

**File: imports/ui/Signup.js**

```
Meteor.call('users.insertotp',1234);
```

Comment: Have you Imported the file in /server/main.js or somewhere in it's import chain?

Comment: I have import of db file in signup.js but not used.And call method is also at signup.js. have included a [github](https://github.com/mgonekar/Meteor-Test-App) so you can view the project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `imports/api/db.js` file is imported on the Client but not on the Server.

Your `client/main.js` defines some routes, among which `imports/ui/Signup.js` which does import the `imports/api/db.js` and calls the Method right away.

On the other hand, your `server/main.js` imports only `imports/api/users.js`, which does not import other api file.

Therefore your Client knows the Method, hence it is able to print the log in the *browser* console, thanks to Meteor *latency compensation* a.k.a. *optimistic ui* a.k.a. client stub. But your Server does not know it, hence it responds with a 404 error.

Simply also import the db file in your server main entry file, and Meteor will do its magic.